# Alter variables between embedded tcl-scripts

Tags: variables, tcl, argument-passing

I have two embedded Tcl-scripts (`main.tcl`, `secondary.tcl`) which have to pass variables back and forth. Depending on the results of `main.tcl` before running `secondary.tcl` certain predefined variables in `secondary.tcl` have to be altered. Then `secondary.tcl` has to pass some variable to `main.tcl` to define how to continue.

Example:

```
#main.tcl

# Here there is first some script which give some results
# Let's say for now result==0 or 1 and some variable "res" 

if { result==0 } {
    set var1 $res
} else {
    set var2 $res
}

# Depending on which of the variables is set, the corresponding
# variable should be altered in secondary.tcl

source /path/to/secondary.tcl

# Now the result in secondary.tcl has to be inserted in this tcl-script
set res_sec $result_secondary

# Rest of script is executed
```

The secondary tcl-script looks like this

```
#secondary.tcl

set var1 some_value1
set var2 some_value2

# Rest of script is executed

set result_secondary some_result  ;# This variable has to be passed to main.tcl

# End of script
```

I hope it's clear what I'm trying to do. I know that in some tcl-scripts they use 'parameter' and then using: `secondary.tcl -parameters "var1 $res"` results in only changing `var1` in `secondary.tcl`. But I couldn't find out how to do that.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

As long as you `source` the scripts into the same interpreter context, they'll share variables by default. (Indeed, if you *don't* want sharing you need to take extra steps, such as using namespaces or separate interpreters.) Thus, all you need to do is to decide what variables are expected going in, and what variables going out.

In your case, you're conditionally setting either `var1` or `var2` going into `secondary.tcl`, and always setting `result_secondary` going out to `main.tcl`. Going out is easy — you've got that part right already! — but your `secondary.tcl` needs a little adjustment. What it needs is a ways to detect if the variables have been set (if they aren't, you can adjust behaviour as you desire, perhaps using a default or whatever). That's easy:

```
if {[info exists var1]} {
    puts "var1 was set to $var1"
} else {
    set var1 "default var1 value"
}
```

---

If the scripts are in different interpreters, things get more complicated because you've got to get past the isolation enforcement. (That's even more important when you're dealing with multiple processes, or even multiple computers.) Yet I think the simplest thing is what you're requiring here; if I'm wrong, edit your question to be clearer (or ask another one).

Comment: Thanks Donal,
This seems to work exactly as I wanted it to work. Yet since there are about 25 different variables to set it starts to clutter the `secondary.tcl`. Is there any possible way that might give a little cleaner code such that I don't have to use 5 lines per variable?
In any case, this does work, thanks.

Comment: @user25946 The usual approach is to define a `proc` which does all the hard work in secondary. So you can source it at any time (you only need to `source` it once, e.g. at the beginning) and call it with the right parameters. (using `source` as `proc` replacement is possible, but I don't recommend it)

Comment: I tried using a `proc`, but for some reason I was unable to call the `proc` unless it appeared in the code before I call it. Yet I know that it should be possible to put the `proc`'s at the end of the code and still call it from anywhere in the code. Can you tell me how I can accomplish that? Do I have to link to it in some way?

Answer (score 0):

Not sure, never really tried this. I think you need to save your variables to a file and read them back in the other script. If you save them as Tcl code (`set foo bar` and so on) you can just `source` the file in the other script and they automagically become live variables in that script.

```
# script0.tcl:
set foo bar
...
set f [open script1.tcl w]
puts $f "set foo $foo"
close $f


# script1.tcl:
set foo bar


# script2.tcl:
source script1.tcl

if {$foo eq "bar"} {
    ...
}
```